# Why am I getting an "missing expression" error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting this error

```
"ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 112 Column: 24
```

when I execute this code

```
select * 
  from sds.input_control 
 where effective_date between Date TO_DATE(:StartDate) and Date TO_DATE(:EndDate)
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

- You need a format for `to_date` such as
  `to_date(:EndDate,'yyyy-mm-dd')`
- Existence of the `Date` qualifier between keywords  `between` and `to_date` has no sense in your case. Moreover `Date` is a reserved keyword, and cannot be used as a column name for `Oracle's SQL`.

Comment: Well if `Date` were a field name also would be out place. My gues is try to do a cast to date

Comment: Thanks Barbaros for the solution

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from sds.input_control
where effective_date between Date TO_DATE(:StartDate) and Date TO_DATE(:EndDate) 
                             ????                         ????
```

What is this "Date" thing? Remove it.

Also, provide appropriate format mask for `TO_DATE` function, if you are providing strings as StartDate and EndDate, e.g.  `to_Date(:startdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')`. Don't rely on Oracle's implicit conversion.

The whole query would look like

```
select * 
from sds.input_control 
where effective_date between TO_DATE(:StartDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy') and 
                             TO_DATE(:EndDate  , 'dd.mm.yyyy')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to SQL queries. Really it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is trying to convert twice the string to a date.

DATE literals and TO_DATE similar jobs and return datetime data types when called. From the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm):

> To specify a DATE value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian
>   calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example:
>
> `DATE '1998-12-25'`
>
> The ANSI date literal contains no time portion, and
>   must be specified in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. Alternatively you can
>   specify an Oracle date value, as in the following example:
>
> `TO_DATE('98-DEC-25 17:30','YY-MON-DD HH24:MI')`
>
> The default date format
>   for an Oracle DATE value is specified by the initialization parameter
>   NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

Remove either DATE or TO_DATE to make it work. Also take into account that if the strings in :StartDate and :EndDate have a time component (hour/minute/second), DATE literals do not support it and you need TO_DATE.

Additionally, it is recommended that when using TO_DATE you explicitly set the date format in the string. That way, if in the future someone changes the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter your application will not break and stop working.

With all that said, the most common solution would likely be:

```
select * 
  from sds.input_control 
 where effective_date between TO_DATE(:StartDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and TO_DATE(:EndDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Or adjust the format mask accordingly to the varchar2 data coming into those variables.